# Overlaying text in Preview

Tags: catalina, pdf, preview

I have a piece of sheet music, and I'd like to replace certain symbols before printing. The official tool for this job is the text box tool in Preview. You type the text and set the background to white. Done.

Except that the text box has margins that are quite large. Since space is limited, those margins cover elements that should not be covered.

The workaround I use is to have white rectangles cover the to-be-replaced symbols and then overlay those with a transparent text box. But this takes more work.

My question is: can the text box margins be reduced or eliminated? If not, is there a better solution than my workaround?

(Note: I use Catalina. Perhaps Preview supports this in Big Sur but not Catalina, so please tell me if that's the case.)

Comment: Preview is a decent PDF tool but there are others out there some with trial periods so you can try before you buy. I use PDF expert and it is pretty good but I am not sure about the margin thing in PDF Expert as I have never had to use that feature. So look around for PDF utilities available on macOS you will likely find one that suits your needs and wallet.

Comment: As @SteveChambers says, Preview is a decent tool.  But not really designed as a PDF editor. My choice is PDFPen. Can certainly do precise text boxes. See if it works for you by downloading the trial. And there are lots of others.

Comment: If the PDF has come directly from notation software (i.e. it's vector graphics with font characters), then using a drawing package like Inkscape, Adobe Illustrator, or Graphic (on the Mac App Store) will provide you better options for adjusting and replacing symbols. Affinity Designer is a little bit flakey at importing PDFs, and can replace some symbols with rubbish. Preview is a jack of all trades, but master of jack...

Comment: @benwiggy I actually have Graphic, but it imports the PDF with all kinds of black blocks.

Comment: @benwiggy Also: unfortunately all symbols have been exported as shapes, which means I can't directly edit them. So even without the black blocks, this wouldn't make editing them in a vector editor more convenient than an app like Preview.

Comment: I edit PDFs of music a lot. What app are you using to create the PDFs? Sounds like the font glyphs are not being recognised.

Comment: I've purchased the PDFs from musicnotes.com. The file info I see is "PDFCreator Version 1.5.0" and "PDFsharp 1.50.5147 (www.pdfsharp.com) (Original: GPL Ghostscript 9.05)".